# How to get flextable::vline to create single border

Tags: r, flextable

I want to display a single vertical border using the `flextable` package in R, but either I can't get it to work or there's a bug in the package (version 0.4.4):

```
library(flextable)
library(officer) # needed to define border properties

std_border = officer::fp_border(color="orange", width = 1)

# dataset to be used for examples
dat <- head(iris[c(1:5, 51:55, 101:105),])
ft <- regulartable(dat)
border_remove(x = ft)

# add internal borders
hline(ft, i = 3, border = std_border)
vline(ft, j = 3, border = std_border)
```

The result is this:

[image: flextable results, not as intended]

As intended, there is a horizontal line at the bottom of the third data row (starting with Sepal.Length = 4.700); so, `hline` seems to work as intended. However, I'm having trouble with `vline`: although there is a vertical line at the right edge of the Petal.Length column, there is also an undesired vertical line at the left edge of that column which I can't get rid of. I only want a single vertical line at the right edge of the specified column 3, which is what I understand to be [the documented behaviour for `vline`](https://davidgohel.github.io/flextable/reference/borders.html#examples).

Is this a bug in `flextable` 0.4.4 or could someone please help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I think it's a bug solved in the dev version. You can try the dev version by running devtools::install_github("davidgohel/flextable")

Comment: @DavidGohel, that did the trick! Could you please post this comment as an answer so that I can select it? Also, please push the current dev version of flextable to CRAN, since this an important bug that renders flextable unusable for many purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an issue and has been solved in flextable `0.4.5`.